# In Python, trying to filter out item from dict using pop

Tags: python

I'm pulling data from an API call, the JSON output has some specific keys that I want to get rid of, for the most part I've used pop('id', None) but I have a circumstance where the item has a nested list. i.e.

```
[
   {
      "enabled":true,
      "is_local":true,
      "name":"no_squash",
      "policy_type":"nfs-export",
      "rules":[
         {
            "access":"no-squash",
            "anongid":"None",
            "anonuid":"None",
            "atime":true,
            "client":"*",
            "fileid_32bit":false,
            "id":"6680ab71-1823-48fc-bc84-920059d218c5",
            "index":1,
            "name":"no_squash.1",
            "permission":"rw",
            "policy":{
               "id":"e399c67e-595a-8b21-18dc-678164e360bd",
               "name":"no_squash",
               "resource_type":"nfs-export-policies"
            },
            "policy_version":"ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5",
            "secure":false,
            "security":[
               "krb5",
               "krb5i",
               "krb5p",
               "sys"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "version":"ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5"
   }
]
```

More so the rules section, how do I target ['rules']['id'] specifically and remove it?

```
  check = requests.get(standard_url+api_version+"/nfs-export-policies", headers=auth_headers, verify=False)
  centry = check.json()['items']
  for item in centry:
      item.pop('id', None)
      item.pop('location', None)
```

The above has already removed the id key from the initial entry but not the subelement.

I've worked out that I can achieve the desired results with nested for loops, but is there a better way?

Raw JSON as received from the API get call:

```
{'continuation_token': None, 'total_item_count': 1, 'items': [{'name': 'no_squash', 'id': 'e399c67e-595a-8b21-18dc-678164e360bd', 'enabled': True, 'is_local': True, 'location': {'name': 'fbstaines03', 'id': 'a7c7d4ad-b515-4f6b-a396-562cdad2063d', 'resource_type': 'arrays'}, 'version': 'ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5', 'rules': [{'name': 'no_squash.1', 'id': '6680ab71-1823-48fc-bc84-920059d218c5', 'policy': {'name': 'no_squash', 'id': 'e399c67e-595a-8b21-18dc-678164e360bd', 'resource_type': 'nfs-export-policies'}, 'access': 'no-squash', 'anongid': None, 'anonuid': None, 'atime': True, 'client': '*', 'fileid_32bit': False, 'index': 1, 'permission': 'rw', 'secure': False, 'security': ['krb5', 'krb5i', 'krb5p', 'sys'], 'policy_version': 'ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5'}], 'policy_type': 'nfs-export'}]}
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Do you want to remove id from every dict object in rules?

Comment: I want to remove the id from everywhere, since that would likely change if the action was posted back to the system

Comment: Can you show the JSON fragment with 'items' key and what your expected output should be. Also, bear in mind that deleting a key from a dictionary (and its associated value) is normally done with *del* unless you need to original value of the key you're trying to remove

Comment: I just appled a nested for loop on item['rules'] which does work, I'm curious if there's a better method

Comment: Can you please show the expected output using that list in the question?

Comment: @Stuart I've tried using del.  it complains about type.

Comment: @DarrenMiller *del* will raise an exception if the key to be removed doesn't exist. Using *pop* is convenient if you want the key's original value or if you don't know if the key exists. See my answer for suggested usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC it looks as though any 'id' key in any dictionary needs to be removed. If so, this is best dealt with recursively:

```
import json

J = """[
   {
      "enabled":true,
      "is_local":true,
      "name":"no_squash",
      "policy_type":"nfs-export",
      "rules":[
         {
            "access":"no-squash",
            "anongid":"None",
            "anonuid":"None",
            "atime":true,
            "client":"*",
            "fileid_32bit":false,
            "id":"6680ab71-1823-48fc-bc84-920059d218c5",
            "index":1,
            "name":"no_squash.1",
            "permission":"rw",
            "policy":{
               "id":"e399c67e-595a-8b21-18dc-678164e360bd",
               "name":"no_squash",
               "resource_type":"nfs-export-policies"
            },
            "policy_version":"ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5",
            "secure":false,
            "security":[
               "krb5",
               "krb5i",
               "krb5p",
               "sys"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "version":"ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5"
   }
]"""

def rmid(e):
    if isinstance(e, dict):
        e.pop('id', None)
        for v in e.values():
            rmid(v)
    elif isinstance(e, list):
        for v in e:
            rmid(v)

data = json.loads(J)

for d in data:
    rmid(d)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "enabled": true,
    "is_local": true,
    "name": "no_squash",
    "policy_type": "nfs-export",
    "rules": [
      {
        "access": "no-squash",
        "anongid": "None",
        "anonuid": "None",
        "atime": true,
        "client": "*",
        "fileid_32bit": false,
        "index": 1,
        "name": "no_squash.1",
        "permission": "rw",
        "policy": {
          "name": "no_squash",
          "resource_type": "nfs-export-policies"
        },
        "policy_version": "ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5",
        "secure": false,
        "security": [
          "krb5",
          "krb5i",
          "krb5p",
          "sys"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "version": "ffffffff-d747-c55b-0000-0000411034c5"
  }
]
```